# Can you say "maintaining something is high"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This sentence from a book makes sense to me semantically--*I understand all the terms in it*--but not syntactically.

> Living plant collections are insurance policies, although maintaining the premiums is high.

I think it's correct to say "the premiums are high", but what does "maintaining the premiums is high" mean?

A little bit background: the author is arguing that we need to preserve apple cultivars, and they can only be preserved as collections of living trees, which is therefore considered "insurance policies."

Comment: ***maintaining the premiums is high*** is the correct version. Don't forget that the subject is a single thing: maintaining something. This is in principle similar to saying that ***selling shoes is profitable***. The act of selling shoes is profitable, not the shoes.

Comment: @CookieMonster I assume you'd find "the shoes are expensive" more agreeable than "selling shoes is expensive"?

Comment: They are both correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is correct to say *is high* rather than *are high*, I wouldn't use this phrase as written. We don't -- at least I don't -- say *maintaining something is high*.  We say that the *cost* of maintaining it is high. If we just referred to premiums, we could say that they are high, because it is clear that a premium is something that you pay for.

If I were the writer's editor, I would suggest an alteration to one of these:

> Living plant collections are insurance policies, although the premiums are high.
>   Living plant collections are insurance policies, although maintaining the premiums is costly/expensive.
>   Living plant collections are insurance policies, although maintaining the premiums comes at a high cost.